# Unity: How to Register types from alternate file

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I am using Unity as IOC container. I have few services derived from IService interface. There are common services used across multiple clients and but there are also services per client as well.

So i m registering these services with container as

```
// common services used by Client A and Client B
container.RegisterType<IService, CommonWordService>("ClientA_Word", new InjectionConstructor(somevalue));                
container.RegisterType<IService, CommonPdfService>("ClientA_Pdf", new InjectionConstructor(somevalue));                
container.RegisterType<IService, CommonWordService>("ClientB_Word", new InjectionConstructor(somevalue));                
container.RegisterType<IService, CommonPdfService>("ClientB_Pdf", new InjectionConstructor(somevalue));                

// Client C specific services
container.RegisterType<IService, ClientCWordService>("ClientC_Word", new InjectionConstructor(somevalue));                
container.RegisterType<IService, ClientCPdfService>("ClientC_Pdf", new InjectionConstructor(somevalue));                

// Client D specific services
container.RegisterType<IService, CleintDWordService>("ClientD_Word", new InjectionConstructor(somevalue));                
container.RegisterType<IService, ClientDPdfervice>("ClientD_Pdf", new InjectionConstructor(somevalue));
```

Now every time we get new client i have to keep updating this registration code. So i thought storing this mapping outside.

I know that Unity does have option to [Load the Configuration from Alternative Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660935(v=pandp.20).aspx). However i think the schema of this alternate file needs to match with [Unity's configuration schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914(v=pandp.20).aspx). (Correct me if i am wrong)

I have JSON file where i store other client related key-value information. I thought of using the same file to store the Unity mapping.
But not sure how do i do this? All the service will be in same Assessmbly
Below is my potential JSON file.

```
[
  {
    "clientid": "ClientA",
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
     "unitymapping" :
     {
       "ClientA_Word": "CommonWordService",
       "ClientA_Pdf": "CommonPdfService",
     }
  },
  {
    "clientid": "ClientB",
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "unitymapping" :
         {
           "ClientB_Word": "CommonWordService",
           "ClientB_Pdf": "CommonPdfService",
         }  
  },
  {
    "clientid": "ClientC",
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
     "unitymapping" :
         {
           "ClientC_Word": "ClientCWordService",
           "ClientC_Pdf": "ClientCPdfService",
         }  
  },
  {
    "clientid": "ClientD",
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",   
    "unitymapping" :
         {
           "ClientD_Word": "ClientDWordService",
           "ClientD_Pdf": "ClientDPdfService",
         }
  }
]
```

**Update1**
So this how I'm registering the types from json file.

```
    var container = new UnityContainer();
            var settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MySettings>>(File.ReadAllText("MySettings.json"));                
            var services = Assembly.Load("MyNamespace.Services");
            foreach (var item in settings)
            {    
                foreach (var mapping in item.unitymapping)
                {
                    var t = services.ExportedTypes.First(x => x.Name == mapping.Value);
                    container.RegisterType(t, mapping.Key, new InjectionConstructor("somedata"));
                }
            }
```

However when I try to resolve `_container.Resolve<IService>(key)`; I get error

> The current type, MyNamespace.Services.IService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Comment: "Now every time we get new client i have to keep updating this registration code. So i thought storing this mapping outside." Is that a bad thing? Especially since custom code seems to be required per client. Having this configuration where it is, does make everything very explicit.

Comment: "But not sure how do i do this?". What about loading that config file, reading its values and selecting the component to register based on that value? What exactly is it that you don't know how to do?

Comment: btw, do all clients use the same application instance at the same time?

Comment: @Steven please see update1. custom service is only required if new client is not using common service. 90% of the time new client will use common service. So in that case I don't want to keep updating code, instead I just add new entry in JSON file.